# need to make this into a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

i need to convert this over to a recursive function. the program basically prints out all variations of a string.

```
def comb(L):          
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                  
                # check if the indexes are not
                # same
                if (i!=j and j!=k and i!=k):
                    print(L[i], L[j], L[k])
                      
# Driver Code
comb([1, 2, 3])
```

output:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Comment: If the code already implements the functionality that you need, why do you want to change it to be recursive?

Comment: Maybe it is an assignment or something

Comment: What's the question?  I suggest reading this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3]))` works. If you need to do it recursively, please see [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) -- an attempt and concrete question is the expected protocol for being on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

- Every permutation of a list can be made by picking a value from the list & putting it at the front of every permutation of what is left in the list after taking that value out.  (Note that the "what is left" part is a smaller list than what you started with.)
- When your list is small enough, it is the only permutation.